# What would happen if photons had a mass equal to 1/100 of a hydrogen atom?

Tags: science-based, physics, light

As we know, light has no mass. Well light having mass is the primary problem with fast(er) than light travel. Thinking about this classic, yet sad problem made me wonder, what would happen the the world if light photons suddenly had equal mass of 1/100 of Hydrogen atoms?

Comment: I'm sure somehow everything as we know it would cease to exist.

Comment: Would they still travel at light speed?

Comment: @RobWatts You suggest "light not travelling at the speed of light"?

Comment: @bowlturner Yeah, that's usually how these questions turn out...

Comment: @TrEs-2b  Technically photons already have mass.  Since photons have energy when moving they have mass by Einstein's e = mc2 .  They have no mass when at rest.  You could rephrase the opening line "light has no rest mass".  (and 1/100 of a hydrogen atom would be a very large increase in mass/energy)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you know, I like these questions because it's not a matter of *if* they'll cause destruction, it's *how much* destruction they'll cause.

Comment: This sounds like a question for xkcd's: [what-if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/)

Comment: *Well light having mass is the primary problem with fast(er) than light travel.* What do you mean by this?

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: The idea of using the relativistic mass equivalent as per $E=mc^2$ as actual mass has been dead for decades. When a physicist today says "mass", they mean *by definition* the invariant mass (which is not a rest mass for a photon because photons do not rest. They *always* move at the speed of light, as everything with zero invariant mass does), see [this answer at physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133395/50583).

Comment: @Hohmannfan I think they mean to suggest "light not traveling at the speed light travels in _our universe_."

Comment: Sure, you'd get faster than light travel. But only because light is moving slower. Assuming the actual speed limit (the speed of propagation of information) is independent of the properties of electromagnetism in particular (really, your change is "magic" as far as we can tell, so you need plenty of assumptions), the actual speed limit stays the same. The reason we call it the speed of light is mainly because light was the first thing that was measured to move at the speed of light, and the name basically stuck - but it's not a property of light, really.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear, just... no. No the photon does not "technically" have a mass. Please never write this again. See the note of ACuriousMind.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Note that introducing a mass for the photons would have fundamental implications on the electromagnetic force and thus large consequences on many parts of the physics as we know it.

But that has been treated by other answers or in the comments below.

---

But if, out of curiosity, we handwave that away, we can see that there would be a lot of implications of this that you have to take care of otherwise, as @bowlturner suggested, the result is massive destruction. For example:

## Doomsday 1

[According to someone on Reddit's calculations](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2n6zo0/how_many_photons_per_second_would_hit_a_1_cm/) as a rough estimate, $10^{17}$ photons hit a square centimeter in full sunlight each second. That converts to $10^{21}$ photons per square meter.

Now consider your heavy photons. Using the non-relativistic calculation for kinetic energy (note that the relativistic calculation would be even greater), we get $K=0.5mv^2=0.5mc^2\approx 7.5\times 10^{-13}~\rm J$ per photon.

That means each square meter will be receiving about $7.5\times 10^8~\rm J$ per second. Compare that to the $6.3\times 10^{13}~\rm J$ of [the nuclear bomb that was dropped on Hiroshima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy). We're getting that much energy per $10^5$ square meters of area, or the area of circle with a 178 meter radius. The initial fireball produced by the nuclear bomb was 370 meters in diameter. So the energy delivered is comparable to that of being near ground zero of a nuclear explosion.

Keep in mind, that's the energy delivered *per second* by your heavy photons.

In other words, the Earth is going to be obliterated. Absolutely and completely.

## Doomsday 2

Another issue with the first scenario is that it violates conservation of mass and energy - a lot of it suddenly comes out of nowhere. Let's try slowing them down enough that their kinetic energy is equal to the energy they had beforehand.

Using a photon somewhere in the visible spectrum, $0.5mv^2=K=E\approx 2~\rm{eV}=3.2\times 10^{-19}J$. Solving for velocity with the heavier mass, we get $v=138~\mathrm{km/s}\;.$ That doesn't sound so bad.

...until you notice that that's less than [escape velocity from the sun's surface (617km/s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities). Also, from the Earth you only need to go 42km/s to escape the Sun's gravity well, so going 138km/s isn't going to be enough to get a photon from the Sun to the Earth.

So photons can't reach the Earth, the Earth goes dark and freezes, and everybody dies. Whoops.

## Doomsday 3

Okay, so what happens if instead of reducing their speed we reduce how many there are? Using my previous estimate numbers, $3.2\times 10^{-19}~\rm J$ per photon compared to $7.5\times 10^{-13}~\rm J$ per heavy photon means a reduction to about one one-millionth of current levels.

Of course, that's *way* higher than the [bond dissociation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy) of any known type of bond. So rather than being absorbed and providing heat, these photons are going to be blowing chemicals bond apart. So the photons are still deadly.

## Doomsday 4

In each of the above scenarios, I've intentionally ignored quantum mechanics. What happens if we take quantum mechanics into account?

Well, photons are electromagnetic waves, so that means the electromagnetic force is affected. That affects how electrons are bound to an atom, and how atoms would bind together to form compounds.

So if you aren't going to handwave away quantum mechanics, all molecules are going to just kinda fall apart.

---

Note that in each of these scenarios I'm only focusing on a single aspect of why things would go horribly wrong. There are going to be additional things causing havoc that I haven't mentioned, such as in the first scenario the ramifications of conservation of mass and energy no longer being true.

Comment: This is completely wrong. You can't just calculate the impact of massive photons without acknowledging that a massive mediating boson would introduce an exponentially decaying factor into Coulomb's law, and effectively making the electromagnetic force more akin to the weak force, which is completely invisible at the classical level (with the low mass in the question, it might be a *bit* more visible, but none of these scenarios actually reflect what would happen). Without long-range (i.e. massless) electromagetism, the world as we know it, even atoms, would not exist.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's why I have my note - I know there are a lot of other reasons why this is going to be a disaster, but I'm not going to be able to cover them all. Also, it's just as easy to say that somehow the electromagnetic force is unaffected as it is to say that photons suddenly have that much mass.

Comment: I have downvoted because the question is tagged "science-based" and this answer is flat-out wrong scientifically. You've manipulated equations with no respect to the underlying physical phenomena.

Comment: This gets me to wondering--how many photons in the sun?  What's going to happen to it's mass?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Usually when someone asks a question like this, they're not thinking about things at the level of quantum mechanics. Also, I'm not familiar enough with quantum mechanics to give a good answer for what happens at that level. So what I can do is show that even if you handwave away all issues at that level, you've still got tons of problems to deal with in order to make it not be catastrophic.

Comment: *Photons* are inherently quantum mechanical. At the classical level, there are no photons, just the electromagnetic field, and the classical effect of massive photons would be a short-range electromagnetic force. You're applying a *purely classical thinking*  to something that doesn't  even exist at the classical level. That's not science-based, it's scientifically inconsistent.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is it any less science-based than photons having mass? Also, this is worldbuilding, not physics. "Science-based" here is more relaxed than you seem to be thinking.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This isn't Physics.SE. Changing something as fundamental as light changes literally everything in physics, and it simply isn't feasible or even rewarding for one to illustrate each and every aspect that's changed **and** resolve each and every contradiction down the entire standard model for a 100% accurate answer. I would find that a lengthy answer that isn't fit for Worldbuilding.SE - and on here, we're more relaxed and allow a bit of wiggle room for colourful answers.

Comment: He's not talking about fixing everything, he's talking about understanding the raw basics of what a massive carrier boson implies. This isn't nth order stuff, it is the very first thing that needs to be considered.

Comment: @TheAnathema (cc Rob Watts) This isn't nitpicking; it's a major issue here - *the* major issue here, in fact. It's the one thing I think an answer should focus on - and [that's been done](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/37619/627). A couple paragraphs is all it takes to point out this fundamental problem. And if [tag:science-based] is this relaxed, then its definition seems to have fundamentally changed to something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @HDE226868 I didn't say science-based is relaxed, I said that WorldBuilding.SE is typically more relaxed. My point is that the answer you guys are expecting are, as I understand it, either **a**) A fully resolved standard model of physics and quantum mechanics, or **b**) A small answer that basically says "Stuff wouldn't be." Since it's already out of the realm of likelihood for a photon to have mass, I think this answer (which says "Nothing would be, but if we ignored that for a second and looked at the implications...") is quite a wonderful answer, and I personally enjoyed it.

Comment: @TheAnathema That reference was to Rob's wording, not yours - apologies for the confusion. But referring to your points here: a) No, nobody's expecting that (I think). It's just one simple part. b) It's *not* out of the likelihood for a photon to have mass. A (admittedly a little naïve/simplified) view would be to view the neutral Z bosons (neglecting the charged W$^{\pm}$ bosons) that carry the weak force as massive bosons. The difference only comes about when the Higgs mechanism breaks the symmetry that arises when unifying the weak and electromagnetic forces. That's a really simple thing.

Comment: I agree with the others that the introduction of mass on photons would have much higher consequences than what your scenarii illustrate. However, on WB, we could handwave that away, and see some other effects. But in order to be more upfront about that, I edited one sentence at the start of the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Very not good.

In quantum field theory, interactions are mediated by force carriers. The range of these force carriers depends on their mass. Photons are the force carriers for electromagnetism. Being massless is why EM has an infinite range.

Mass would change that.

All of electromagnetism would be range limited, and to fairly microscopic distances. The earth's magnetic field would vanish, and magnets would stop working, because they can no longer affect things at a distance.

The only things that could produce light would make light with wavelengths in the gamma spectrum of energies. Normal light wouldn't happen.

Photons wouldn't travel at c  - in fact, it doesn't solve the speed limit problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Modifying the mass of the photon has far more fundamental impacts on the way electromagnetism and in particular propagation of light work than the silly doomsday scenarios in the currently top-voted answer.

Comment: Also, most chemical bonds depend an interactions between electrons. For that matter IIRC the electric charge has something to do with hadrons and electrons forming atoms. Essentially all matter would be plasma.

Answer (score 11):

What's the difference between electromagnetism and the "weak" force? Mass! Massive bosons would mean that the electic force would have a short range.  This would mess up the existance of atoms.

Comment: This. $\hbar c \approx 200\,\mathrm{MeV\,fm}$, and the presumed mass is about $10\,\mathrm{MeV}$ meaning that atoms would be confined to radii of 40 or 50 times the size of the nucleus which would totally change their character. And there would be no long range radiation at all. Again: a few tens of femtometers at most.

Comment: No radiation means no radiative cooling of gasses, so clouds would not collapse, as is the case for dark matter in the real universe.

Answer (score 8):

Not good.

The Sun emits approximately $4.2 \cdot 10^{44}$ photons/s, and with your stated mass, that would be $7 \cdot 10^{15}$ kg/s. That means it would have radiated away all its mass in just $3.3$ billion years, slightly disappointing for us living $4.5$ billion years after it was formed.

So, for something a bit more destructive, a mass moving at the speed of light (per definition) exerts an infinite force on things it hits. In short, everybody dies, and absolutely every part of the universe is torn apart. Solar cells may be slightly more efficient though.

Comment: The sun would not put out so many. It would put out a number based on the energy produced.

Comment: @JDługosz Yeah, but that is not great for us either. What the consequences are depends on the exact interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Then the coulomb force would be $$F_E=\frac{Qq}{4πε_0r^2}e^{-\frac{mγr}{ħ}}(1+{\frac{mγr}{ħ}})$$ with $F_E$ being the electric force, $Q$, and $q$ being the electric charges,  being the $ħ$ being the reduced Planck constant, $ε_0$ being the permittivity of free space, $r$ being the distance between the charges, $mγ$ being the mass of photons.

This means that the force between two electric charges would decrease with distance exponentially instead of simply with the square of the distance.  This also means that it would be possible to figure out that photons would have a mass of 1/100 the mass of a hydrogen atom based on how the force between two electric charges would decrease with distance.

If light had a mass of 1/100 the mass of a hydrogen, then it would be possible to travel faster than photons as photons would travel at less than $c$, but it would not be possible to travel faster than $c$ as while $c$ is referred to as the speed of light it really does not depend on there being light, but instead depends on the Lorentz factor. So if you want a universe where it's possible to travel faster than photons, then having massive photons would allow this, but if you want a universe where there is no cosmic speed limit, you would need to make more changes than simply having massive photons.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing would change from our perspective because all the information about what would have happened had the change not occurred would still be present in the universe due to unitary time evolution. So, even though the universe looks like having become completely different with short range electromagnetic interactions, atoms suddenly decaying as a result, etc. etc., you can transform to a different basis in Hilbert space by applying the inverse time evolution operator to the time before the change happened and then the time evolution operator using the wrong Hamiltonian that doesn't include the change of the mass of the photon.

If you write down the quantum state of the universe in terms of this new basis, then the universe looks the same as what it would have been, had the photon stayed massless. In particular we would still exist, observing the same universe that from our perspective hasn't changed at all.

Comment: I don't think you can time transform across mass introducing boundary just like that. Hamiltonian is discontinuous at that point.